# Compile unsafe Haskell

Tags: performance, haskell, llvm, ghc

It seems that Haskell tries to be a safe language, and tries to help the programmer from mistakes. For example, `pred`/`succ`throws error if outside, and `div 1 0` also throws. What are these safe Haskell computations, and what overhead do they cause?

Is it possible to turn off this kind of safety for GHC, since they should not be necessary in a bug-free program? And can that cause better speed performance?

For the C backend, there was an option `-ffast-math`. Is there any such performance options for the LLVM backend or LLVM?

Comment: This would be very useful.

Comment: @telephone I take it the bug-free programs you're planning on writing are going to be used by mistake-free users on a malware-immune errorless OS.

Comment: @AndrewC I understand that bug-free programs typically never exists. But I wanted an overview of what additional safety Haskell/GHC introduces. And also know if it is possible to control them in some manner.

Comment: @telephone Teenagers and novices will flock to this like bugs to a florescent light. "I can spped up my program with a single import. Why isn't this the default? I don't need to divide by zero or use numbers bigger than the largest Int anyway." Experienced, sensible folk used to the real world put the error checking in, and know to speed up their code primarily by understanding algorithm design and how their code is executing. I can't see a good general use for this malfeature.

Comment: @telephone (Some flourescent light have electrified grills in front of them. None of them are actually daylight.)

Comment: ...and some people know what they want and do what they want.

Comment: @telephone I'm not challenging your freedom, I'm questioning your wisdom.

Comment: @AndrewC Unfortunately, I often hear “write it in C if you need speed”. But Haskell + unsafe features is still *safer* than C. We just want to make using unsafe features of Haskell a preferred alternative to switching to some *entirely unsafe* language like C.

Comment: @AndrewC I think it is wise to don't bother about the low-level implementation, and instead rely on writing natural code. But I still want to know what overhead Haskell adds, if this comes from Prelude or the compiler, and if this overhead can be a problem. I do not pre-optimize a program in this case, I only want to learn more about coding in Haskell :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

*The benchmark was indeed seriously flawed in the previous version of this answer. I apologise.*

### The problem and the solution, if we don’t dig too deep

Indeed, `pred`, `succ` and other functions raise exceptions when various errors occur, such as overflow and division by zero. Normal arithmetic functions are just wrappers around low-level unsafe functions; as an example, look at the implementation of `div` for `Int32`:

```
div     x@(I32# x#) y@(I32# y#)
    | y == 0                     = divZeroError
    | x == minBound && y == (-1) = overflowError
    | otherwise                  = I32# (x# `divInt32#` y#)
```

You can notice that there are *two* checks before the actual division is performed!

These aren’t the worst ones, however. We have bounds range checking for arrays — sometimes it slows down the code greatly. This particular problem is traditionally solved by providing special variants of functions with checks disabled (such as `unsafeAt`).

As pointed out by Daniel Fischer [here](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2011-November/096747.html), there *is* a solution which does let you to disable/enable checks with a single pragma. Unfortunately, it is quite cumbersome: you’ll have to copy [the source of GHC.Int](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.2.0.1/doc/html/src/GHC-Int.html) and cut out the checks from every function. And GHC.Int isn’t the only source of such functions, of course.

If you really want to be able to disable the checks, you’ll have to:

1. Write all the unsafe functions you’re going to use.
2. Either write a file which would contain the rewriting rules (as described in Daniel’s post) and import it, or just do `import Prelude hiding (succ, pred, div, ...)` and `import Unsafe (succ, pred, div, ...)`. The latter variant wouldn’t allow as simple switching between safe and unsafe functions, though.

### The root of the problem and the pointers to the real solutions

Suppose that there is a number which is known not to be zero (hence the checks aren’t needed). Now, *to whom* it is known? Either to compiler, or to you. In the first case we can expect the compiler not to perform any checks, of course. But in the second case our knowledge is useless — unless we can somehow tell the compiler about it. So, the problem is: how to encode the knowledge we have? And this is a well-known problem, with multiple solutions. The obvious solution is to make the programmer expicitly use the unsafe function (`unsafeRem`). Another solution is to introduce some compiler magic:

```
{-# ASSUME x/=0 #-}
gcd x y = ...
```

But we functional programmers have *types*. And we’re used to encoding information with types. And [some of us](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/PeanoArithm.lhs) are great at it. So, the smartest solution would be to either introduce a family of `Unsafe` types, or switch to dependent types (i.e. learn Agda).

For more information, please read about [non-empty lists](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Non-empty_list). The concern there is more about safety than performance, but the problem is same.

### It isn’t so bad

Let’s try to measure the difference between safe and unafe `rem`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MagicHash #-}

import GHC.Exts
import Criterion.Main

--assuming a >= b
--the type signatures are needed to prevent defaulting to Integer
safeGCD, unsafeGCD :: Int -> Int -> Int
safeGCD   a b = if b == 0 then a else safeGCD   b (rem a b)
unsafeGCD a b = if b == 0 then a else unsafeGCD b (unsafeRem a b)

{-# INLINE unsafeRem #-}
unsafeRem (I# a) (I# b) = I# (remInt# a b)

main = defaultMain [bench "safe"   $ whnf (safeGCD   12452650) 11090050,
                    bench "unsafe" $ whnf (unsafeGCD 12452650) 11090050]
```

The difference doesn’t seem to be that huge:

```
$ ghc -O2 ../bench/bench.hs && ../bench/bench

benchmarking unsafe
mean: 215.8124 ns, lb 212.4020 ns, ub 220.1521 ns, ci 0.950
std dev: 19.71321 ns, lb 16.04204 ns, ub 23.83883 ns, ci 0.950

benchmarking safe
mean: 250.8196 ns, lb 246.7827 ns, ub 256.1225 ns, ci 0.950
std dev: 23.44088 ns, lb 19.06654 ns, ub 28.23992 ns, ci 0.950
```

### Know your enemy

A clarification of what safety overhead is being added.

First of all, if a safety measure can lead to an exception, you can learn about it [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Exception.html). There is a list of all types of exceptions that can be thrown.

**Programmer-caused exceptions (no artificial overhead):**

- `ErrorCall`: caused by `error`:
- `AssertionFailed`: caused by `assert`.

**Exceptions thrown by standard libraries (rewrite the library and the safety overhead is gone):**

- `ArithException`: division-by-zero is one of those. Also covers overflow/underflow and some less common ones.
- `ArrayException`: happens when the index is out of bounds or when you try to reference an unfefined element.
- `IOException`: don’t worry about those, the overhead is bleak in comparison to the IO overhead.

**Runtime exceptions (caused by GHC, unavoidable):**

- `AsyncException`: stack and heap overflows. Only minor overhead.
- `PatternMatchFail`: no overhead (the same way the `else` in `if...then...else...` doesn’t create any).
- `Rec*Error`: happens when you are trying to address a non-existend field of a record. Causes some overhead since a check of field’s existence has to be performed.
- `NoMethodError`: no overhead.
- a multitude of exceptions concerning concurrency (deadlocks and so on): I have to confess that I haven’t got a clue about them.

Second, if there exists a safety measure that does not cause an exception, I would really like to hear about it (and then file a bug against GHC).

### A remark

By the by, `-ffast-math` wasn’t affecting any checks (they were done in Haskell code, not in C). It was simply making floating-point operations faster at the expense of precision at some edge cases.

Comment: 3x overhead was worse than I had expected... Safe Haskell should be disabled by default and instead be enabled by some compiler/LANGUAGE option. Also the whole Prelude should be disabled by default, in my opinion.

Comment: Does optimization make these numbers better?

Comment: @telephone: the benchmark was compiled with `-O2` (I have just clarified that in my answer to avoid further confusion).

Comment: @telephone: When speed is needed, we can just replace safe functions to unsafe by hand; by the by, today I’ve started writing a library to make it easier, and if you’re willing to help, contact me!

Comment: @telephone It's easier to speed up a slow correct program than to fix a fast buggy one. Disabling safety checks when it makes a difference between "fast enough" and "not fast enough" makes far more sense than having to manually turn on safety checks when you decide performance doesn't matter. If you know at the outset that every bit of code in your project needs the best possible performance (this is quite a rare situation), don't write it in Haskell, write it in C.

Comment: @Ben I agree that premature optimization is not constructive. But I don't want help from the compiler, unless I ask for it. I want to keep things simple and clean, especially for all primitives (Prelude).

Comment: @ArtyomKazak Sure I am willing to help (if I am qualified). But I am not sure if writing a (another) Hackage library is constructive. As Ben said, this is premature optimization. But it could also be the case that the compiler is too safe. Hence I wrote this question :)

Comment: @telephone Reformatted the answer, added another section. The second and fourth sections are new.

Comment: @ArtyomKazak I am happy with your extended answer

Comment: I make this an accepted answer, since it answers many of the questions. If someone has more to add, for example about GHC, they can add a new answer also.

Comment: @telephone There was no 3× overhead! Sorry for that. I didn’t notice that `safeGCD` had been defaulted to `Integer -> Integer -> Integer`…